# Replace element in a scalable way JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, replace

I have an Object like this one:

```
{
  '/': [ 'a', 'd', 10 ],
  a: [ 'e', 20 ],
  e: [ 30 ],
  d: [ 40 ]
}
```

Is there a effective solution to replace the letters in the arrays with their equivalent value?
the result intermediate solution should be like this:

```
{
  '/': [ 30 , 20 , 40 , 10 ],
  a: [ 30, 20 ],
  e: [ 30 ],
  d: [ 40 ]
}
```

and final solution the sum of all numbers in the arrays:

```
{
  '/': [ 100 ],
  a: [ 50 ],
  e: [ 30 ],
  d: [ 40 ]
}
```

I found a solution, but it's not scalable for a really big Object (hundreds of keys and dozens of letters in the array), so I am looking for suggestions. Thanks.

My solution is a for loop in each element of all arrays, concatenate the equivalent array of the letter element, remove the letter and continue the loop. The loop continues until all arrays are just numbers with a while loop.

Comment: Why is `a`, `d` and `e` equivalent to `30`, `20` and `30` respectively? Why is there three items in `/` and four in your second object?

Comment: If it's a big object, perhaps you should just do the conversion when you're doing a lookup? Like converting `bigObject['a'][0]`. I don't know what you're going to use the object for.

Comment: because the letter 'a' has been replace with ['e' , 20] and then the letter 'e' has been replace with [30], letter 'd' has been replace with [40]. Final is '/': [ 30 , 20 , 40 , 10 ]. Every letter has to be replace with numbers. All the letters in the array are the keys of the obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only loops through each item once, and creates a sum for each property within the object *while it loops through each reference* to a property. It does that by creating a recursive loop via the helper method `calcNumbers()`.

```
let obj = {
  '/': [ 'a', 'e', 10 ],
  'a': [ 'e', 20 ],
  'e': [ 30, 'd' ],
  'd': [ 40 ]
  'b': [ '/' ]
}
```

- The program starts by looking at `/` and it's first position 0, which contains a reference to `a`.
- It goes to `a` and starts at the first position there - a reference to `e`.
- It then goes  to `e` that has a reference to `d` in position 1.

  - `d` is "40" so `e` is *reduced to* (30+40=) "70".
  - `a` is in that case (70+20=) 90 which `a` is *reduced to*.

    - Position 0 in `/` is therefor 90.
- Position 1 in `/` is a reference to `e`, but `e` have already been reduced to "70".
- `/` is finally *reduced to* (90+70+10=) "170".
- That means that `b` just can do a lookup in `/` which have already been calculated: "170"

That's the entire chain of loops that occurs.

```js
function reduceObj(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    obj[key] = calcNumbers(obj, key)
  }
  
  console.log(obj)
}

function calcNumbers(obj, key) {
  let totalNumber = 0, calculatedNumber = 0;
  let arr = obj[key];
  const TOTAL_NUMBER = 0;

  //console.log(key, arr)
  
  for (let value of arr) {
    if (typeof value == 'number') { totalNumber += value }
    else { 
      obj[value] = calcNumbers(obj, value);
      totalNumber += obj[value][TOTAL_NUMBER];
    }
  }

  return [totalNumber];
}

let obj = {
  '/': [ 'a', 'e', 10 ],
  'a': [ 'e', 20 ],
  'e': [ 30, 'd' ],
  'd': [ 40 ],
  'b': [ '/' ]
}

reduceObj(obj);
```

Comment: Nice! I like it! It is probably the most efficent way to solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

First Sort the keys based on there array element length, so this will help in replcaement logic

```
let keys = Object.keys(yourObject).sort((x,y) => d[x].length > d[x].length ? 1 : -1)
```

Then perform iteration on each key

```
keys.forEach((subArray)=>{
    yourObject[subArray] = yourObject[subArray].map((item)=>{
       
        if(yourObject[item]){
            item = yourObject[item]
        }
        return item
    })
    yourObject[subArray] = yourObject[subArray].flatMap(x=>x)
})

console.log(yourObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Again, I am not sure there is a clean solution for this... I may change the process.
This is the real Obj

```
{
  '/': [
    'gqlg',     'hchrwstr',
    'lswlpt',   'plmdrbn',
    'rjwmjd',   'stqq',
    'zjhqnlrr', 'zssdlnc',
    282555
  ],
  gqlg: [
    'hnr',     'mdzdht',
    'gfjqbdp', 'gqlg',
    'nvjqp',   'dwhr',
    'rzsrp',   'vdcbg',
    2458912
  ],
  hchrwstr: [ 'rzsrp', 'shlhgj', 'slwwgc', 340423 ],
  rzsrp: [
    'rzsrp',    'dvzvmsjz',
    'zfn',      'pgwng',
    'fzsngr',   'gqlg',
    'mbsjjzft', 'pmsgd',
    'smd',      1980230
  ],
  dvzvmsjz: [ 149823 ],
  zfn: [ 'cwzbljh', 'fbmww', 'jsst', 1281815 ],
  shlhgj: [
    'wtlngn', 'cjmv',
    'tns',    'lrths',
    'rwn',    'pmldlbbh',
    2303101
  ],
  slwwgc: [ 856006 ],
  lswlpt: [ 278572 ],
  plmdrbn: [ 'fmzjhrq', 227129 ],
  fmzjhrq: [ 'rrjjsvm', 9749 ],
  rrjjsvm: [ 66652 ],
  rjwmjd: [ 'twcrf', 'zwmmrqj', 125294 ],
  twcrf: [ 492080 ],
  zwmmrqj: [ 311312 ],
  stqq: [ 'hpgbcvtb', 'llbthqc', 'rzsrp', 'whmdbn', 863300 ],
  hpgbcvtb: [ 'mqjfvg', 807734 ],
  mqjfvg: [ 170328 ],
  llbthqc: [ 117161 ],
  whmdbn: [ 94821 ],
  zjhqnlrr: [ 'bzzvj', 'ddzmvh', 'dsjd', 'nnzvl', 649511 ],
  bzzvj: [ 'wjtlg', 'zfn', 609500 ],
  wjtlg: [ 97079 ],
  ddzmvh: [ 'cpvfln', 'hgrnmh', 'hjpgf', 'mghmb', 'pvdwhmcr', 1065714 ],
  cpvfln: [ 'sthhc', 274478 ],
  sthhc: [ 'slsj', 'vsvvprg', 719559 ],
  slsj: [ 178013 ],
  vsvvprg: [ 102783 ],
  hgrnmh: [ 'mrnmbbt', 'wpvssts', 'mvrlcvj', 2310065 ],
  mrnmbbt: [ 245579 ],
  hjpgf: [ 749373 ],
  mghmb: [
    'bgrcsdc', 'btjq',
    'gqlg',    'gtwdqw',
    'hgrnmh',  'jts',
    'jvp',     'jvrjcv',
    593716
  ],
  bgrcsdc: [ 235762 ],
  btjq: [
    'bvrcqb',  'drslln',
    'dwzpblb', 'gqlg',
    'hgrnmh',  'hvb',
    'rqtc',    'vsdz',
    'wrnftqh', 0
  ],
  bvrcqb: [ 'gqlg', 82050 ],
  drslln: [ 258102 ],
  dwzpblb: [ 302466 ],
  hnr: [ 'fjd', 'mqp', 681200 ],
  fjd: [ 450522 ],
  mqp: [ 'rzsrp', 0 ],
  pgwng: [ 218271 ],
  mdzdht: [ 'gqlg', 'tvd', 0 ],
  gfjqbdp: [ 143536 ],
  tvd: [ 238491 ],
  hvb: [ 'hgrnmh', 'smmwg', 0 ],
  wpvssts: [ 305634 ],
  smmwg: [ 'rzsrp', 62967 ],
  fzsngr: [ 142687 ],
  rqtc: [ 'pbzhfsg', 'rzsrp', 'shlhgj', 0 ],
  pbzhfsg: [ 41865 ],
  nvjqp: [ 'gcq', 0 ],
  gcq: [ 'mslhm', 'rzsrp', 0 ],
  mslhm: [ 41304 ],
  mbsjjzft: [ 'stgszvmj', 572294 ],
  stgszvmj: [ 'dthcrbmr', 'shlhgj', 'zfn', 206580 ],
  dthcrbmr: [ 'lhp', 'npf', 'qbgrjr', 0 ],
  lhp: [ 37925 ],
  npf: [ 77162 ],
  qbgrjr: [ 48767 ],
  wtlngn: [ 'gqlg', 0 ],
  cjmv: [ 140919 ],
  tns: [ 'qhhtgsvz', 464329 ],
  qhhtgsvz: [ 68979 ],
  vsdz: [ 'jsrqjjtc', 'shlhgj', 347553 ],
  jsrqjjtc: [ 245991 ],
  wrnftqh: [ 252462 ],
  gtwdqw: [ 299426 ],
  jts: [ 542874 ],
  jvp: [ 258220 ],
  jvrjcv: [ 623520 ],
  pvdwhmcr: [
    'bhmmsbmb', 'bjwbvcq',
    'hgrnmh',   'ltvtrtth',
    'prtqcb',   'rmn',
    'shlhgj',   'tmzcmb',
    'vlbqvps',  'wmmfp',
    0
  ],
  bhmmsbmb: [ 'nccjwf', 0 ],
  nccjwf: [ 'drwhjfjn', 206638 ],
  drwhjfjn: [ 291772 ],
  bjwbvcq: [ 'zfn', 0 ],
  ltvtrtth: [ 'fwtwqvn', 'mcgcc', 'zfn', 'zzsnz', 634082 ],
  fwtwqvn: [ 'rqndc', 'rzsrp', 'shlhgj', 124999 ],
  rqndc: [ 45124 ],
  mcgcc: [ 'ngvwhnvf', 249817 ],
  ngvwhnvf: [ 207616 ],
  cwzbljh: [ 134952 ],
  zzsnz: [ 273014 ],
  prtqcb: [ 'dtr', 'rzsrp', 199012 ],
  dtr: [ 'gqlg', 'grwpbs', 'hgrnmh', 647580 ],
  grwpbs: [ 59390 ],
  rmn: [ 'gtnvc', 'rsnqlfsz', 486781 ],
  gtnvc: [ 28523 ],
  rsnqlfsz: [ 'hgrnmh', 'nsfhtthc', 0 ],
  nsfhtthc: [ 284747 ],
  lrths: [ 'hgrnmh', 'pfc', 'vlshvmvj', 'wsn', 703772 ],
  mvrlcvj: [ 121034 ],
  pfc: [ 'gqlg', 0 ],
  vlshvmvj: [ 122494 ],
  wsn: [ 'hgtqj', 'shlhgj', 435231 ],
  hgtqj: [ 214202 ],
  pmldlbbh: [ 263722 ],
  rwn: [ 279589 ],
  tmzcmb: [ 138557 ],
  vlbqvps: [ 'nmfnf', 123659 ],
  nmfnf: [ 'jhpnd', 287610 ],
  jhpnd: [ 290482 ],
  wmmfp: [ 94749 ],
  dsjd: [
    'bwjp',   'gqlg',
    'hgrnmh', 'jntt',
    'vmph',   'zvg',
    865190
  ],
  bwjp: [ 117739 ],
  dwhr: [ 364612 ],
  pmsgd: [ 'wbppspwq', 12648 ],
  wbppspwq: [ 38834 ],
  jntt: [ 286866 ],
  vmph: [ 'fnvpsr', 'gfnvsznj', 224084 ],
  fnvpsr: [ 'flz', 'rzsrp', 552801 ],
  flz: [ 106168 ],
  smd: [ 'drsld', 'gqlg', 419969 ],
  drsld: [ 85885 ],
  gfnvsznj: [ 'fqb', 'hdhmbtj', 'lzdq', 'rlvqmwv', 'rzsrp', 339460 ],
  fqb: [ 465476 ],
  hdhmbtj: [ 'gqlg', 'rzsrp', 'vrmrnt', 135597 ],
  vdcbg: [ 261780 ],
  vrmrnt: [ 418820 ],
  lzdq: [ 425741 ],
  rlvqmwv: [ 'gqlg', 'shlhgj', 398966 ],
  zvg: [ 85701 ],
  nnzvl: [ 'wwzsf', 0 ],
  wwzsf: [ 105177 ],
  zssdlnc: [ 'nfgh', 'zfn', 166004 ],
  nfgh: [ 102281 ],
  fbmww: [ 179734 ],
  jsst: [ 'flp', 0 ],
  flp: [ 99924 ]
}
```

Comment: You know, `rzsrp` is calling itself in its first item: `rzsrp: [ 'rzsrp', 'dvzvmsjz', 'zfn', 'pgwng', 'fzsngr', 'gqlg', 'mbsjjzft', 'pmsgd', 'smd', 1980230 ],`

Comment: `rzsrp` is also referencing `gqlg` (position 6 above)  which is referencing `rzsrp` (position 7 below).

Comment: `gqlg: ['hnr', 'mdzdht', 'gfjqbdp', 'gqlg', 'nvjqp', 'dwhr', 'rzsrp', 'vdcbg', 2458912],`

Comment: ...I think I found the problem. Thank you for the comment!